# How can I install tesseract-ocr to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, ocr, tesseract

I need help installing tesseract-oce to Eclipse, i'm downloading the android ndk at the moment, but i don't know what shall I do or what do i need to download, where to download the tesseract library and how to enclude it to Eclipse and use it

can anyone help me pease?
thank you,,

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use some already built library for android, like: https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two, or http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/

After you add library to your project, you just need to create a TessBaseAPI instance somewhere in your code, init() it with path to language files and stuff, setImage() and get text that it found.

Of course you need to find language files and stuff, but that's easy.

Be warned though, I "played" with this lib a long time ago, so I may be way off.